# Regex for this match

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

So I have sample url `http://citrine.rcd.dev:8080/image/1582_125x125.jpg`

It's built with the code:

```
    public string GetDerivativeUrl(long imageId, bool preserveTransparency, DerivativeSize size, bool allowCache, string designTags, int quality)
    {
        string tags = (designTags == null || designTags.Trim().Length == 0) ? "" : designTags;
        string imageFormat = (preserveTransparency) ? "png" : "jpg";
        if (quality > 0)
            return String.Format("{0}/image/{4}{1}_{2}.{3}?qv={5}", GetUrlPrefix(imageId, allowCache), imageId, size.GetPixelSize(), imageFormat, tags, quality);
        return String.Format("{0}/image/{4}{1}_{2}.{3}", GetUrlPrefix(imageId, allowCache), imageId, size.GetPixelSize(), imageFormat, tags);
    }
```

I want to get `http://citrine.rcd.dev:8080/image/1582.jpg` from `http://citrine.rcd.dev:8080/image/1582_125x125.jpg`

How do I do this?

Comment: what's wrong with return `String.Format("{0}/image/{3}{1}.{2}", GetUrlPrefix(imageId, allowCache), imageId, imageFormat, tags);` ?

Comment: So do you want to change the string after it was created in this method or do you want to change the method so it returns the string you want?

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) to get the filename part from the path and then replace `"_.*?\."` by `"."`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead of using a Regex.

```
string url = @"http://citrine.rcd.dev:8080/image/1582_125x125.jpg";
int index = url.LastIndexOf('_');
if (index != -1)
   url = url.Substring(0, index) + Path.GetExtension(url);
```